# False positive in Bash condition

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am writing a bash script to check on multiple servers if Tomcat 5 is installed. When running the script, even if the find command stored in the variable `command` returns nothing, the tomcat variable is still set to '1' in the if statement.

I know there must be something wrong with my if statement but I'm not sure what. Below is the function that runs the command on the remote server

```
function search() {

        local login=$1
        local server_fqdn=$2

        local command="sudo find / -name \"tomcat-5*\""
        ssh -oBatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=6 $login@$server_fqdn "$command"
        if [ "$?" = 0 ];
        then
                echo "Tomcat found"
                tomcat=1
        else
                echo "No tomcat here!"
        fi
}
```

How can I get the function to enter the 'else' condition if `command` returns nothing?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is: `find` returns `0` when not failing regardless of whether it found anything or not, you may be assuming behavior similar to `grep`, but that's not the case. You could capture its output `res=$(find ...)` and test if it is not empty (`test -n`), but...

But honestly, this is a rather odd way to detect present of installed SW which is quite error prone. To say the least, imagine you've left a file with notes for later: `my_tomcat-5_hints`.

Perhaps ask your packaging manager if being used on the host... or at least check for existence of specific file(s)/dir(s)?

You should generally not need to be superuser to tell either and if you do, it's a little odd to `ssh` in as one user just to `sudo` in the next step if it really was needed.